# Why can't save changes on GeoServer layers via QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, geometry, windows

I am using `QGIS 2.14` on Windows 10, and `GeoServer 2.8.3` on Windows 2008 Server (VPS).

QGIS manages my GeoServer layers with Web Feature Service. I would like to change the geometry or attributes of the layers stored in GeoServer with QGIS, but I can't. The added points appear on the web map, but I **can't delete or modify** these points and don't know why. No errors reported, seems like the changes have been saved. Furthermore I can't draw new lines and polygons: in the attribute panel the data appears, but it has no geometry so I can't visualize it.

Where's the problem?

Comment: Where are stored the data ?

Comment: ShapeFiles On a VPS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider to migrate your data to a spatial database, like [Postgis](http://postgis.net).
Shapefile is not a supported format for [WFS-T](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs).

Check [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/data.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank You! I installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS and created PostGIS layeris in GeoServer. 

But when i want to change geometry in QGIS via WFS it drops an error:

": Error performing insert: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry linestring mulylinestring"

I've read the type of the geometry isn't OK, eg. 'linestring' and 'multilinestring'

How could i solve this problem to update my layers?